# I get the node Key, not the Child key from snapshot Swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm retrieving posts in a node from Firebase database, but I get the Node key instead of the Child key, which I'll use to delete entries from database. The line where I get the key value I `guard let firebaseKey = snapshot.key as? String else { return }`. I tried `snapshot.children`but it has no `key`parameter to choose. How do I get to it then?
Many thanks as usual.

Th complete function is :

```
func displayAlerts(setCompletion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        print("                     MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray before displayAlert snapshot is: \(MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray)")
        print("                     self.userAlertNotificationArray before displayAlert snapshot is: \(self.userAlertNotificationArray)")

        if self.userAlertNotificationArray.count == 0 {
           ref = Database.database().reference()

            ref?.child("Continent").child("Europe").child("Country").child("Italy").child("Region").child("Emilia-Romagna").child("City").child("Bologna").child("Community").child("Alert Notifications").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
                print("         snapshot is: \(snapshot)")
                guard let data = snapshot.value as? [String :[String:String]] else { return }

                guard let firebaseKey = snapshot.key as? String else { return }

                data.values.forEach {
//                    let firebaseKey = data.keys[]

                    let dataLatitude = $0["Latitude"]!
                    let dataLongitude = $0["Longitude"]!
                    let type = $0["Description"]!
                    let id = Int($0["Id"]!)

                    print("firebaseKey is:\(firebaseKey)")
                    print("dataLatitude is: \(dataLatitude)")
                    print("dataLongitude is: \(dataLongitude)")
                    print("type is: \(type)")
                    print("id is: \(id)")
                    print("Key is: \(firebaseKey)")
                    print("data is: \(data)")

                    let doubledLatitude = Double(dataLatitude)
                    let doubledLongitude = Double(dataLongitude)
                    let recombinedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: doubledLatitude!, longitude: doubledLongitude!)

                    let userAlertAnnotation = UserAlert(type: type, coordinate: recombinedCoordinate, firebaseKey: firebaseKey, title: type,id: id!)
                    self.userAlertNotificationArray.append(userAlertAnnotation)  // array of notifications coming from Firebase
                    MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray.append(recombinedCoordinate)
                }


                            print("Firebase alerts posts retrieved")

                print("                 MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray after  displayAlert snapshot is: \(MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray)")
                print("                     self.userAlertNotificationArray after  displayAlert snapshot is: \(self.userAlertNotificationArray)")
                self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.userAlertNotificationArray)
                setCompletion(true)

            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood where my error was. I was obviously getting the parent key.
Inside a `for in` loop for the `snapshot.children` I declared a variable to hold the children snapshot value and then get my values as before. I just didn't realise I had to enter the dictionary coming back from Firebase as a snapshot to read the entries. I hope this will help other beginning programmers as this was a lot of frustration for me, but as usual, learning the hard way pays off big time.

So the complete rewritten function is now:

```
func displayAlerts(setCompletion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        print("                     MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray before displayAlert snapshot is: \(MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray)")
        print("                     self.userAlertNotificationArray before displayAlert snapshot is: \(self.userAlertNotificationArray)")

        if self.userAlertNotificationArray.count == 0 {
            ref = Database.database().reference()

            ref?.child("Continent").child("Europe").child("Country").child("Italy").child("Region").child("Emilia-Romagna").child("City").child("Bologna").child("Community").child("Alert Notifications").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print("         snapshot is: \(snapshot)")
                guard let data = snapshot.value as? [String :[String:String]] else { return } // checking if the snapshot is the dictonary in the form of [String :[String:String]] else return

                for snap in snapshot.children {
                    let alertSnap = snap as! DataSnapshot  // casting the snapshot children is the dictonary in the form of [String:String]
                    let childrenKey = alertSnap.key
                    let alert = alertSnap.value as! [String:String]
                    let dataLatitude = alert["Latitude"]!
                    let dataLongitude = alert["Longitude"]!
                    let type = alert["Description"]!
                    let id = Int(alert["Id"]!)!
                    print("Node Key is: \(snapshot.key)")
                    print("childrenKey is:\(childrenKey)")
                    print("dataLatitude is: \(String(describing: dataLatitude))")
                    print("dataLongitude is: \(String(describing: dataLongitude))")
                    print("type is: \(String(describing: type))")
                    print("id is: \(String(describing: id))")

                    print("data is: \(data)")

                    let doubledLatitude = Double(dataLatitude)
                    let doubledLongitude = Double(dataLongitude)
                    let recombinedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: doubledLatitude!, longitude: doubledLongitude!)

                    let userAlertAnnotation = UserAlert(type: type, coordinate: recombinedCoordinate, firebaseKey: childrenKey, title: type,id: id)
                    self.userAlertNotificationArray.append(userAlertAnnotation)  // array of notifications coming from Firebase
                    MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray.append(recombinedCoordinate)
                }



                print("Firebase alerts posts retrieved")

                print("                 MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray after  displayAlert snapshot is: \(MapArray.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray)")
                print("                     self.userAlertNotificationArray after  displayAlert snapshot is: \(self.userAlertNotificationArray)")
                self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.userAlertNotificationArray)
                setCompletion(true)

            })
        }
    }
```

One thing that I don't understand dough is the down voting thing, if they at least leaved a comment to help improving questions it would be useful, otherwise  it's only adding to the already big frustration of whom has come to find help for a problem that he's facing.
Hope that this last comment also helps. This is a great community and really I wouldn't have come to this point without.
It's great pride to be part of it.
Cheers.